# Understanding redirected if-statement in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, test

```
if [ -z "$OPTION" ] # if option is not given(empty) then:
    then
        command1 --defaultOption
    else 
        command1 $OPTION
fi \
  2> >( function1 "$DETAILS" ) \
  < <( command2 "$OTHER_DETAILS" )
```

I am seriosly puzzled how directing stderr to a file and feeding a file into stdin interact with an if statement.
Well known things are:

`2>filename# Redirect stderr to file "filename."
2>>filename# Redirect and append stderr to file "filename."
command < input-file > output-file
< input-file command > output-file`

My guess would be:

command2 generates a file which is forwarded either to command1's stdin with --defaultOption (if $OPTION is empty, then case) or to command1's stdin with $OPTION (if $OPTION is not empty, else case).
stderr of command1 is redirected to function1 (which as an example might be some sort of progress-bar display).

So my questions are:

Are the whitespaces between the brackets `< <` and `> >` necessary? Is it actual an append (whitespace ignored), or a "double" redirect?
Am I missing an interaction between brackets and braces `>(` and `<(`?
Does it somehow influence the evaluation of the the if? Or is only `-z $OPTION`tested?

Can I understand what's going on better if I write the outputted file of command2 to the disk, then check for the option and read it again in the if statement?

```
command2 "$OTHER_DETAILS" --out=file.txt
if [ -z "$OPTION]
  then
    command1 --defaultOption --in=file.txt 2>function1
  else
    command1 "$OPTION" --in=file.txt 2>function1
fi
```

This is part of a script I found over there:
http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/V4L_capturing/script
(lines 912 through 924)

Answer (score 2):

`<(cmd)` and `>(cmd)` are shell grammar (called process substitution). They are replaced by a file path i.e.

```
cmd1 <(cmd2)
```

becomes

```
cmd1 /path/to/file
```

The content of the file is the output of `cmd2` thus it can be read only but not written to. An example:

```
start cmd:> ls -l <(echo foo)
lr-x------ 1 hl hauke 64  5. Jan 03:49 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[3125128]
```

In this case `ls` sees `/dev/fd/63` as an argument. In your case this path becomes part of a redirection. Thus the whitespace is mandatory. `> >(cmd)` is "redirect stdout to a temprary file which contents become the input of cmd" whereas `>>(cmd)` causes an error because the shell expects a path (or whitespace) after `>>`. `>>'(cmd)'` "works" because now `(cmd)` is considered a file:

```
start cmd:> echo foo >>'(cat)'

start cmd:> cat \(cat\) 
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

A `>( )` is an idiom called "Process Substitution" and is used to replace some code or function for "the place of a file".

The `>( function1 "$DETAILS" )` is connecting to the `stdin` of `function1`.
Judging by the name I assume that function1 is a function already defined (in code read before where the function is being used) in the script you are using/reading.
Any command that so choose to connect to `stdin` (many times cat) inside `function1` will read the input from `stdin`

Similarly, `<( command2 "$OTHER_DETAILS" )` is connecting to the `stdout` of `command2` (which, I will assume, is a function inside the script). Any `echo`, `printf` and many other could write to such `stdout` from inside the code of `command2`.

The end result is that the `stderr` (2>) of the code executed inside the `if` if being connected to some other code inside the script.
And, the output of the `command2` is also being connected to code inside the `if` (which must be command1 judging by the code you presented).

Both re-directions are similar (not exactly equal) to this code:

```
command2     | command1
command1 2>1 | function1
```

Comment: you need to write command 2's stderr into function 1 as well in your straight-forward example to make it really like. good answer though